# Setting up a two dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get a simple two dimensional array set up such as:

```
$transactionType [0][] = array ('B', 'S', 'F', 'M', 'D', 'R', 'O');
$transactionType [1][] = array ('Boat purchase', 'Start up', 'Fee', 'Maintenance', 'Deposit from client', 'Rent', 'Other');
```

So that:

$transactionType [0][0] would return 'B'

$transactionType [1][0] would return 'Boat purchase'

$transactionType [0][1] would return 'S'

$transactionType [1][1] would return 'Start up' etc

The following works but appears a little messy to me. Is there is neater way of doing it?

```
$transactionType = array (array('B', 'Boat purchase'), array('S', 'Start up'), array('F', 'Fee'), array('M', 'Maintenance'), array('D', 'Deposit from client'), array('R','Rent'), array('O', 'Other'));
```

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Comment: What is the desired output? The first code snippet doesn't create the same array as the one in the second.

Comment: consider marking an answer as answer if it helped you, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
$transactionType = array();
$transactionType [0][] = array ('B', 'S', 'F', 'M', 'D', 'R', 'O');
$transactionType [1][] = array ('Boat purchase', 'Start up', 'Fee', 'Maintenance', 'Deposit from client', 'Rent', 'Other');
```

You pretty much had it right the first time :).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a key => value approach be more suitable?

```
$transactions = [
   'B' => 'Boat purchase',
   'S' => 'Start up'
];

$transactionIds = array_keys($transactions);
$transactionValues = array_values($transactions);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have:

```
$transactionType0 = array ('B', 'S', 'F', 'M', 'D', 'R', 'O');
$transactionType1 = array ('Boat purchase', 'Start up', 'Fee', 'Maintenance', 'Deposit from client', 'Rent', 'Other');
```

Then:

```
$transactionType = array();
foreach($transactionType0 as $key => $value) {
    $transactionType[$key] = array($transactionType0[$key], $transactionType1[$key]);
}
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => Boat purchase
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => S
        [1] => Start up
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => F
        [1] => Fee
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => M
        [1] => Maintenance
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => D
        [1] => Deposit from client
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => R
        [1] => Rent
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => O
        [1] => Other
    )

)
```